# The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

Upon startup of Tomcat I am getting the following message in catalina.out -

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
```

My website comes up and functions fine so this is not any kind of critical issue that I know of.

I did some searching but could really not find out what it does and how to remedy it.

Any help as to why I get this and how to resolve it?

I am running Apache Tomcat/9.0.41

Here is a snippet of the connector part of my server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               redirectPort="443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->

             <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="2000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
               compression="off"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/xml,text/javascript,text/css"
               useSendfile="false"
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/conf/my-keystore.jks"
               keystorePass="xxxxxxx" />

             <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="2000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
               compression="off"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/xml,text/javascript,text/css"
               useSendfile="false"
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/conf/my-keystore.jks"
               keystorePass="xxxxxx" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
      <!--    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" /> -->
```